# Using Server.MapPath() to generate img src, not working

Tags: asp.net

This seems like a basic question, but I am looking for a proper way of doing this. I am displaying a series of images and their source in view looks like this:

```
src="@Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/App_Data/",photo.ClientId.ToString(),photo.PhotoId.ToString())+photo.FileExt.ToString())"
```

Which compiles to:

```
"c:\users\architect\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\PhotoManagement\PhotoManagement\App_Data\5\62.jpg"
```

I triple checked that the files do exist at this location. Why does the browser refuse to display this image? Is there a workaround so that the code still works on the server when I upload it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Server.MapPath` returns the path of the image **on the server**. Unless the client happens to have an image in *exactly* the same path on their computer, this will not work.

Try using `Url.Content` instead:

```
src="@Url.Content(Path.Combine("~/App_Data/", photo.ClientId.ToString(), photo.PhotoId.ToString()) + photo.FileExt.ToString())"
```

Answer (score 2):

`APP_Data` is a restricted folder intended for Datasources such as Database only. ASP.Net will not deliver a file in here - try it by going to the URL for that image directly (I.E `www.mysite/App_Data/5/62.jpg` ) and you will see the error message **`HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden.`**

Put your images in a folder outside of this and you will be fine, such as a folder in the root Called `Images`

Comment: I changed where my pics are to: C:\Users\Architect\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PhotoManagement\PhotoManagement\Photos\11... But no cigar, pics are not loading. I think there is a problem with browsers not liking C:\...

Comment: Whats your image source in HTML now?

Comment: <img src="c:\users\architect\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\PhotoManagement\PhotoManagement\Photos\11\65.jpg" />

Comment: and have you tried navigating directly to that file, put that in the browser?